# Instructions for a custom post type

Tags: admin

Is there any way to put some instructions for a custom post type inside the post admin at the top of the add/edit page?

I know you can put the instructions inside of a meta box, but at the top would be easier for the user to read....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add help tabs with [`add_help_tab()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_help_tab). You'll need to filter which page you add it to based on the data returned by `get_current_screen()`, but that's simple.